# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 32, 24, 7)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am still figuring out how to resolve this error...
As I have to fixed my first layer of input shape to
`input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, N_PAST, N_FEATURES)`
I am getting errors on any error for LSTM and GRU

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE,N_PAST, N_FEATURES)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_FEATURES)
    ])

    model.summary()

    optimizer =  tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-8, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(
        loss="mse",
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=["mae"]
    )
    model.fit(
        train_set, validation_data=valid_set,validation_steps=100, epochs=100
    )
```

Comment: You should not include batch_size in input shape.

Comment: this was a test question.
It had this statement in the comments:
~~"Whatever your first layer is, the input shape will be 
(BATCH_SIZE, N_PAST = 24, N_FEATURES = 7)
The model must have an output shape of
(BATCH_SIZE, N_FUTURE = 24, N_FEATURES = 7).
Make sure that there are N_FEATURES = 7 neurons in the final dense layer since the model predicts 7 features."~~

Did I understand wrongly?

Comment: Actually batch dimension is considered automatically by model. You don't need to specify it. The model itself will add it with `None` as first dimension. In input_shape you just need specify the other dimensions.

Comment: I am getting another error when i change the input_shape=(N_PAST, N_FEATURES),

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:    Operation expected a list with 24 elements but got a list with 47 elements.

Comment: Apparently tt expects N_PAST to be 24, but it gets 47.

Comment: thanks, i think there a problem in the windowed_dataset as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never a need to give a model a fixed value for the batch_size dimension, tensorflow will handle this dynamically depending on the given data shape.

So in the construction of the model:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, input_shape=(N_PAST, N_FEATURES), activation='relu')
```

When executing summary() this layers should have an input shape of (None, N_PAST, N_FEATURES)

Comment: Thanks for this.
Now I am having issue with my windowed_dataset as it is giving the error 
```tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Operation expected a list with 24 elements but got a list with 47 elements```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add BATCH_SIZE:

```
input_shape=(N_PAST, N_FEATURES)
```